# Using georeferencer in QGIS 2 64bit installation

Tags: qgis, gdal, georeferencing

I tried to use the georeferencer in the new QGIS 2 64 bits for windows. I tried with the standallone installer and with the OSgeo4w installer. The problem is when I load the raster that I want to georeference, all I get is a gray square with a bunch of blurred colors at the top. I tried to use the georeferencer in Vista 64 (8gb of RAM) and in win 7 64 (16 gb of RAM). Also running QGIS as an administrator did not solve the problem.
I used the same image in a 32 bit installation of QGIS 2 and I have not a problem loading it or working with it.

What can I do to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem... it was because it was in JPG.
I had a TIF image, but I wanted to test a thing and saved it as JPG... and I got exactly what's described.

After that, I tried to save it as a BMP, and the image format problem didn't occur again, could be the handling of the JPG format.