# Is there a bug in Georeferencing in QGIS 2.0?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I recently updated to QGIS 2.0. But now, when I need to georeference some pictures, I have serious problems.

When loading the files to be georeferenced, I can see only a part of it in the window, so that working with it is not possible. Zooming out or in, zooming to the layer doesn't help anything:

[image]

First I thought that the size 2362 x 2637 is not suitable to QGIS, so I reduced it to 567 x 633 at 72 dpi, but the problem occurs.

What can I do? Thanks a lot for your hint!!!

Harald

Comment: What operating system are you working on? Do the files open in Gimp? Maybe these JPGs are compressed or with a colour paletting QGIS can not understand.

Comment: Look at this. It may help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72190/problem-with-georeferencer-in-qgis-2-64bit-installation?noredirect=1#comment98466_72190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this ticket:

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8660

the problem could be fixed in QGIS Master.

Try that, or a 32bit build, or another format like png, until QGIS 2.2 is released.

Comment: converting JPG to BMP did the job. So thanks for your hint. By the way: I am working on OS X 10.8.5. All JPG are uncompressed and created with Photoshop CS6.

Comment: Might be that Photoshop uses color spaces like sRGB or scRGB and QGIS can not work with it.